# What is the range limit for uniform real distributions?

Tags: c++, random, c++14

I want to create a random number within the numeric limits of the `double` floating point range. I thought this would be easy:

```
#include <random>                                                                   
#include <cassert>                                                                  
#include <math.h>                                                                

int main()                                                                          
{                                                                                   
    double a = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();                               
    double b = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();                                  

    std::default_random_engine engine;                                           

    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(a, b);                           
    assert(std::isfinite(dist(engine))); // this triggers!

    return 0;                                                                    
}
```

The assert fails for both `clang 3.8.0` and `gcc 5.4.0`, because apparently the result of `dist(engine)` is `inf`. I tried using `nextafter(a,0)` and `nextafter(b,0)` instead of `a` and `b` when constructing `dist` but got the same result.

According to [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution), the methods `min` and `max` should provide the range of numbers that will be returned, but apparently that's not the case:

```
std::cout << dist.min() << ", " << dist.max() << std::endl;
```

The output of this is:

> -1.79769e+308, 1.79769e+308

And, as expected, the following assert triggers, demonstrating the contradiction:

```
const auto rand = dist(engine);
assert(rand <= dist.max() && rand >= dist.min());
```

Again, same result for both compilers. As per the definitions of `min` and `max`, the above assert *shouldn't* be triggering. What's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code exhibits undefined behaviour, as it breaks the following condition:

> N4140 § 26.5.8.2.2 [rand.dist.uni.real]
>
> ```
> explicit uniform_real_distribution(RealType a = 0.0, RealType b = 1.0);
> ```
>
> *Requires:* `a ≤ b` and `b − a ≤ numeric_limits<RealType>::max()`.

To answer your question, the range limit for `uniform_real_distribution` is therefore `[a/2,b/2]` where `a` and `b` are the `lowest` and `max` numeric limit values of your floating point type.

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't have found that.

Comment: @arman This is new to me as well. But the fact that my gcc always returned infinity has been enough of a hint to look at the preconditions.